# Binomial, geometric distributions, conditional

Tags: conditional-probability, binomial-distribution

I have that $$ X_2|X_1 =  Bin(n,p) $$ and $$ X_1 = Geo(\frac{1}{B+1}) $$

I need to find the marginal distribution of $$X_2$$

I know that the joint distribution is given by $$P(X_1,X_2) = P(X_2|X_1)P(X_1)$$

I'm thinking to take the marginal I need to take the sum over X1 however it is getting messy very quickly. Is this the correct approach?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any relationship between the parameters $n,p$ and $X_1$ in the conditional distribution $X_2\mid X_1$? If not, $X_2$ and $X_1$ are independent.

Comment: No relationship that I am aware of. Would that change my approach?